# Error when trying to print out an iterator over (revision_id, depth, revno, end_of_merge) tuples

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, bazaar

If I enter the code:

```
b = Branch.open('directory containing repository')
r1 = 1010 #input revision number
r2 = r1-5 #last revision number that I want to sort to
r1 = b.dotted_revno_to_revision_id((r1,), _cache_reverse=False) #revision ids of r1 and r2
r2 = b.dotted_revno_to_revision_id((r2,), _cache_reverse=False)

test = b.iter_merge_sorted_revisions(start_revision_id=r1, stop_revision_id=r2, stop_rule='include', direction = 'reverse')

for i in test:
    print i[0]
```

The `iter_merge_sorted_revisions` is supposed to return an iterator over (revision_id, depth, revno, end_of_merge) tuples.

So when I print all of the i[0] it should return to me all of the revision_ids between r1 and r2.

And it DOES return them to me all the way up to r2. But I keep on getting an error that stops the rest of my code from running once that for loop finishes.

The error code is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "log.py", line 60, in <module>
for i in revisions:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/branch.py", line 634, in _filter_start_non_ancestors
pmap = self.repository.get_parent_map([rev_id])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/vf_repository.py", line 1882, in get_parent_map
self.revisions.get_parent_map(query_keys).iteritems():
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/groupcompress.py", line 1356, in get_parent_map
return self._get_parent_map_with_sources(keys)[0]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/groupcompress.py", line 1375, in _get_parent_map_with_sources
new_result = source.get_parent_map(missing)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/groupcompress.py", line 2093, in get_parent_map
self._check_read()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/groupcompress.py", line 2051, in _check_read
raise errors.ObjectNotLocked(self)
bzrlib.errors.ObjectNotLocked: <bzrlib.groupcompress._GCGraphIndex object at 0x7fd55e846390> is not locked
```

I do not know what is going wrong because the for loop is completed since it does return to me the last revision that I want. I don't know if I need to somehow manually end the loop, but any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a read lock on the branch before you can access it:

```
b.lock_read()
try:
    test = b.iter_merge_sorted_revisions(start_revision_id=r1, stop_revision_id=r2, stop_rule='include', direction = 'reverse')
finally:
    b.unlock()
```

Comment: What is the problem though? The for loop runs through and exhausts all of the iteration and then the error message is displayed. I ended up using `break` when i = r2 and the error message doesn't have a chance to display itself. This is a little bit of a cheat fix I guess but it works.

Comment: You need to take a lock in order to access a lot of the lower level operations. In some cases you can get away with not locking, for example if all you're accessing is revisions that are on the left hand side history of the branch. That's an implementation detttail though, and you shouldn't rely on that.